# Jackrabbit Repository Migration issue

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

Currently I am trying to migrate the repository of the jackrabbit. Where I did a fresh installation setup and migrated the database contents also, post that tried to create folders inside jackrabbit . If any new upload is happening then the files are in jackrabbit folder, but the old data are not shown in the folders.

When trying to access the particular file in the path it shown as **ItemDoesNotExist**.

Any inputs will be helpful. Thanks in advance